# How to indicate a press in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a TouchableHighlight. I'd like the press of the area to indicate feedback to the user, so they know it was pressed. How can I do this?

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => (this.navToReport(report))}>
  <View>
    <View style={globalStyles.inspectionsItemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.secondaryText}>{this.getTime(report)}</Text>
      <Text style={globalStyles.inspectionsItemAddress}>{this.getAddress(report)}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.secondaryText}>{this.getClientName(report)}</Text>
    </View
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an `activeOpacity` property, [see the docs for details](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/touchablehighlight.html#activeopacity). Or switch to use `TouchableOpacity` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of feedback you are looking for. It could be as simple as setting the [`activeOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#activeopacity) and [`underlayColor`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#underlaycolor) properties on your `TouchableHighlight`. If you want to do something more advanced, you could modify state variables as part of your `onPress` function and adjust your render to do something different based on those (i.e., different color for the `TouchableHighlight`).

I would say try playing with the properties I linked first and see if that's good enough for you.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the activeOpacity out.